# How to redirect user to another html page *ON LOCAL STORAGE* after clicking Submit button

Tags: html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    location.replace("https://www.w3schools.com")
    }
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="text" name="username" pattern="[a-zA_Z].{7,}" title="Unsuccessful Login, Username must contain at least one integer and one letter, and at least 7 or more characters">
    <input type="button" name="B1" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">
    </form>
    </body>
```

Hi, for some reason when I click the submit button, the error does not appear and it just goes directly to the page. How do I make the program check the validation and when it is ok, redirect to a new page??

Comment: The redirection logic should be set into action_page.php

Comment: It would be better if you can provide more code

Comment: I have no clue how to do that. Thats all I have

Comment: @pravinnavle What the code is meant to do is. If the username meets the validation criteria, it loads up the 'test1' page which is in my storage automatically.

Comment: i got it to redirect but the validation is not working

Comment: that's great. welcome :)

Comment: ok wait I'm working on your code

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go by this approach

create a test.php file with the following code :

```
     <form method="post">
                Username: <input type="username" name="username" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{7,}" title="Must contain at least one integer and one letter, and at least 7 or more characters">


            <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>

<?php


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.location = 'your location';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

This will give you the desired functionality. 
NOTE: for this to run, you will need to install xampp or wamp if you are running windows and lamp if you are running linux.

Comment: Look at the code above. I have edited it, now it directly goes to the webpage without looking at validation

Comment: please check the new answer and accept it if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

So here's the answer according to your updated code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function myFunction() {
        window.location.href = 'https://www.w3schools.com';
        return false;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
        <body>
        <form onsubmit="return myFunction()">
        <input type="text" name="username" pattern="^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+){5,}" title="Login Unsuccessful. Username must contain at least one integer and one character, and should be atleast 5 or more characters long" required>
        <input type="submit" >
        </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The `return false;` statement in myFunction is very important here. It will return a false to the obsubmit event which will prevent the form from being submitted. If you remove `return false;` statement then also `window.location` will work but it will appear as if it's not working as the form will get submitted and you will see the same page rather than a redirection to another page.

I have added the onsubmit event which will call the function only when all the inputs are valid

Comment: thanks man. this works but if I put any character such as @ or /, it still redirects. What validation should I put in to stop this?

Comment: can you tell me the exact conditions for validation that you want so that I can tell you the regex for it

Comment: username should be:(at least 5 characters long, have at least 1 letter and integer, no other characters apart from integer and numbers)

Comment: check my updated answer and accept the answer if it has helped you

Comment: now the updated pattern will accept 5 or more characters with atleast one number. it won't accept special characters like @ or / just like the way you want it to work